# approx_percentile() function returns error for negative values in QuestDB

Tags: sql, questdb

When I run the following query on [QuestDB demo site](https://demo.questdb.io/) :

```sql
SELECT approx_percentile(pickup_latitude, 0.99) 
FROM trips 
where pickup_datetime = '2009-01-01'
```

I get the following error:

```
The value -73.997484 is out of bounds for histogram ...
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/aggregation/#approx_percentile), `approx_percentile()` accepts only non-negative argument values.

You can work around the limitation by shifting values by value greater than smallest negative value ( `min(pickup_latitude)` in this case) before and after function call, for instance:

```sql
SELECT max(pickup_latitude), approx_percentile(pickup_latitude+3600, 0.99,3)-3600
FROM trips 
where pickup_datetime = '2009-01-01'
```

This should return:

```sql
max column
-73.965918 -74
```